# How can I find out what prevents a rails app from loading a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling

I have a rails which seemed to be working previously but now after some changes when I go to the root page it takes it infinitely to load it, it just doesn't load it. There're nothing useful in the console either. How can I find out what prevents it from loading the main page? Is it about profiling?

Comment: Is there something in the log file?

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for that you need to post your console logs for further checking

Comment: @ChiragArya, re-read my question.

Comment: I think @ChiragArya is referring to your Rails logs.  eg. `logs/development.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Rails logs, eg. `development.rb`.  You can put `logger.info`, or `puts` statements in your environment.rb, development.rb and application.rb files to see how far Rails is getting in the boot process.  You can also create a dumb initializer named `00_start_init.rb` with a `logger.info` or `puts` statement to see if you're getting as far as initialization. I've found that useful before.

To really understand where you application is hanging, you need to understand the Rails initialization process.  Here is the documentation for Rails version 4.2.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/initialization.html.  Similar documentation exists for every version of Rails.  You can take advantage of understanding the boot sequence by placing log statement at various point in the process.

I'm assuming you're in the development environment.  If so, and the console loads, it's likely not a configuration problem.  It's more likely a problem with your controllers or models.  If the console won't load to a prompt, then it's likely a configuration problem in application.rb, development.rb, an initializer, etc.

You mention profiling, but provide no details about it.  I can't even guess what you're referring to, so the answer is "maybe?".  If you can post the code changes you made since the app last loaded in the browser, that would make it much easier to help you trouble-shoot.